# Adjust gamma of image using ImageSharp

Tags: imagesharp

I'm porting an existing application to .net core and I need to adjust the gamma of an image using ImageSharp.

I've tried `image.Mutate(i => i.Brightness(value));` but it's not quite the same result as the original code which changes the gamma.

The original code uses `imgAttribs.SetGamma(value, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);` but I can't use `System.Drawing.Common` as it's missing a dependency on AWS Lambda.

Is it possible to change the gamma using ImageSharp, if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Gamma adjustment is simply a non linear adjustment of individual pixel values. You don't need a built in function to do it. Loop through the pixels and adjust each one.

Th algorithm, from memory, is something like `Math.Pow(component, gamma);` for each r, g, b component of a pixel.